# getting variable from iOS 7 safari search bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7

For iOS 7, is it possible for me to acquire an answer from the google calculator for example?
Like for example, if I have to convert currency, assume the unit for both term (maybe USD to CAD) is decided by the user, can I get the conversion through the URL on Safari(to access live google calculator)?
If not, is there any way to get these conversions that has their value changing daily?

Comment: You might have to find out the API that google has for those conversion and call those directly within your app. Oh yea, make sure its a public API before you call those APIs.

Comment: What about Objective-C